# Auto Populate a jTextField with NetBeans

Tags: java, swing

I have created a jFrame using NetBeans that opens when a button on the main GUI is clicked to add a new entry.  I want to know if there is a way to supply a unique id for each new entry that shows when the jFrame form is displayed.  Along with a unique id I want to also have a text field createdOn that is auto populated with the current date.

Answer (score 3):

For the life of the JVM executing the program, `hashCode()` may serve as a a unique ID; [`UUID`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) is an alternative. The example shows a new `Date` each time the button is pressed.

Addendum: On closer scrutiny, the [`hashCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#hashCode%28%29) method of `java.util.Date` may not be unique. In particular, "It is *not* required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results." You may be able to use the `long` from `getTime()`, subject to the one millisecond resolution.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128432 */
public class AddTest extends JPanel {

    private static final DateFormat format =
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
    private final List<TestPanel> panels = new ArrayList<TestPanel>();

    public AddTest() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        TestPanel tp = new TestPanel();
        panels.add(tp);
        this.add(tp);
        this.validate();
        Dimension d = tp.getPreferredSize();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d.width, d.height * 8));
    }

    private static class TestPanel extends JPanel {

        public TestPanel() {
            Date date = new Date();
            this.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(date.hashCode())));
            this.add(new JTextField(format.format(date)));
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("AddTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton button = new JButton(new AbstractAction("New") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                TestPanel tp = new TestPanel();
                panels.add(tp);
                AddTest.this.add(tp);
                AddTest.this.revalidate();
                AddTest.this.repaint(); // may be required
            }
        });
        f.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AddTest().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that successive values of `Date` can be at most one millisecond apart.

Comment: Thanks. I am not in front of my code now. I will look at this further when I get home.  It appears that it will work.

Comment: As discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390240),  `repaint()` may be necessary after `revalidate()`.