# refresh JFrame and adding buttons in loop

Tags: java, netbeans-6.9

i am adding a new component to a jframe at run time, than i call

`validate();` and `repaint();`

but nothing is happening

also is there a way to add buttons using a loop so each time enter the loop a new button will be added to jframe at run time

i am using netbeans 9.6.1

Comment: we need to see your code

Answer (score 0):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130167) uses `add()` and `revalidate()` in a button's `actionPerformed()` method to add a `JPanel` of components on each click.