# JPanel dynamically generate outside from its original location

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane, dynamically-generated

I'm dynamically generating some text boxes and labels inside a `JPanel` but when I place that panel inside a `JTabbedPane` it's not generate inside its original location. it always go to somewhere else.

Code inside `JFrame` class constructor:

```
    panel = jPanel1;
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
```

Code inside a `JButton`:

```
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
    lbl.setText("Label");
    panel.add(lbl);

    JTextField txt = new JTextField(12);
    txt.setText("Text field");
    panel.add(txt);
    panel.revalidate();
    validate();
```

The button is use to generate text boxes and labels dynamically. `jPanel1` is a panel placed inside a frame. its works perfectly with directly placed inside a frame but after it is placed inside a tabbed pane it's messing around.

Is there a method to refresh panel and remove components inside it after generating components inside it?

here is the complete Jframe class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author sajithru
 */
public class DynamicTextboxes extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form DynamicTextboxes
     */
    private JPanel panel;

    public DynamicTextboxes() {
        initComponents();
        panel = jPanel1;
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 206, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 258, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab1", jPanel1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(190, 190, 190)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(216, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 211, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 286, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(40, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
        lbl.setText("Label");
        panel.add(lbl);

        JTextField txt = new JTextField(12);
        txt.setText("Text field");
        panel.add(txt);
        panel.revalidate();
        validate();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DynamicTextboxes.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DynamicTextboxes.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DynamicTextboxes.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DynamicTextboxes.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new DynamicTextboxes().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: That looks scarily wrong to me.  Can you produce a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are using `setBounds()`, or something similar, to position components in a `Container` that has some (default) layout lying in wait for your call to `revalidate()`. Instead, invoke `pack()` on the enclosing `Window` before calling `setVisible()`.

Addendum: *I tried using* `pack()` *… but result is still the same.*

Your layout is cutting off the new rows. The example below uses `pack()` to resize the enclosing `Window`. This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4130167/230513) illustrates `revalidate()` and `repaint()`. Also consider using a `JScrollPane`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14858272/230513).

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17165034/230513
 */
public class DynamicTextboxes extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form DynamicTextboxes
     */
    public DynamicTextboxes() {
        initComponents();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(createPanel());
        jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab1", jPanel1);
        add(jTabbedPane1);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(jButton1);
        add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jPanel1.add(createPanel());
        pack();
    }

    private JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
        lbl.setText("Label");
        p.add(lbl);
        JTextField txt = new JTextField(12);
        txt.setText("Text field");
        p.add(txt);
        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DynamicTextboxes().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: The `jPanel1.getLayout()` part might suggest otherwise re the premise of this answer, but an SSCCE can clarify.. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Maybe; as `panel` is a reference to `jPanel1`, the call to `setLayout()` is an identity; I agree completely on the virtue of an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)!

Comment: i tried using pack() instead of revalidate() but result is still the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help but this still doesn't address my problem here. when I place the jPanel1 inside a jTabbedpane panel generate some other location :(

Comment: I don't understand; you can export an [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) if needed.

Comment: I'll try to be more explainable. I want to generate few labels and text boxes dynamically inside a jPanel(in this case jPanel1). so I'm using above mentioned method. its working fine until I placed that jPanel inside a jTabbedpane. So I want to know what I can do to make it work inside the jTabbedpane as it was before.

Comment: The [sscce](http://sscce.org/) above places the panel in a tabbed pane, so I don't understand what you want to do differently.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not following. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/), based on the one I posted above.